# Need help to find derivative of matrix norm

Tags: derivatives, convex-optimization, matrix-equations

$$\min_{W} ||XW-X||_F^2+p_1||W||_1+p_2R(W), W>=0$$
Guys i need help how to find first derivative of this equation
$$R(W)=Tr(W^TX^TLXW)$$
L=Laplacian matrix

Comment: The first and second terms can be handled using standard results on matrix derivatives; the second term is not differentiable (assuming it's the entrywise $\ell_{1}$ norm)

Comment: @nemo just derivative the $$\min_{W} ||XW-X||_F^2$$ and the other use close solution W ?

Comment: For the first term, it's $2X^{\top}(XW-X)$ (assuming these are all square matrices).

Comment: $$2X^T(XW^*-X)+p_1||W||_1+p_2R(W)=0$$ W use close solution ?